# Access html table with htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I would like access the the table contained in a html file. Here is my code:

```
  import java.io.*; 
  import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
  import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
  import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
  import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;


  public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage currentPage = client.getPage("http://www.mysite.com");
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);



final HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) currentPage.getByXPath("//div[@id='table-matches-time']");

   String textSource = div.toString();
    //String textSource = currentPage.asXml();

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("index.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(textSource);

out.close();

    client.closeAllWindows();

  }

 }
```

the table is in this form:

```
   <div id="table-matches-time" class="">
                    <table class=" table-main">
```

but i get this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlDivision
at test.main(test.java:20)
```

how can i read this table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this works (and return me a csv file ;)):

```
    import java.io.*; 
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableRow;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;


    public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage currentPage = client.getPage("http://www.mysite.com");
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("index.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);



   for (int i=0;i<2;i++){

final HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) currentPage.getByXPath("//table[@class=' table-main']").get(i);




   for (final HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()) {

   for (final HtmlTableCell cell : row.getCells()) {
    out.write(cell.asText()+',');
   }
out.write('\n');
   }

   }

out.close();

    client.closeAllWindows();

   }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query is returning a list of nodes, instead of a single div. Do you have multiple items with that id?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of the code:

```
(HtmlDivision) currentPage.getByXPath("//div[@id='table-matches-time']");
```

With:

```
(HtmlDivision) currentPage.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='table-matches-time']");
```

The first method will always return an a collection of elements even if it is one, while the second will always return one element, even if there are more.

**Edit:**

As you have two elements with the same `id` (which is not advisable at all), you should use this:

```
(HtmlDivision) currentPage.getByXPath("//div[@id='table-matches-time']").get(0);
```

That way you'll be getting the first element of the collection. `.get(1);` will get you the second.

Comment: but are two tables with this name.

Comment: this return me:

>HtmlDivision[<div id="table-matches-time" class="">]

but i would get the whole table.

Comment: @emanuele Do you mean that you want the `<table>` element instead of the DIV? The div that came back has the table inside of it.

Comment: i mean that i want a text file with all the data contained in the table, but i don't know how to do this.